# Change main menu in MS Word using Office Addin

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-2013

I am developing Office Addin for MS Word 2013 using Office Javascript API and I need to change the behaviour when user click FileSave or FileSaveAs in the main menu.

Is there any way to replace the default command via Office Javascript API by execute a function with in this addin instead of default behaviour?

Or can I catch somehow BeforeSave event using Office Javascript API?

Or can I develop C# Office Addin that will replace default menu with commands that will execute a javascript function in a specified Office Addin?

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to affect how File/Save As (or Save) works using the JS API.

Affecting the Ribbon (menus) can only be done using Ribbon XML / add in commands. This was added to the Office JS for Office 2016 and is therefore not available for Office 2013. (See the [requirement sets](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets?product=excel).)

Even then, the XML for Office JS does not support manipulating the built-in application Ribbon elements, unlike the full Ribbon XML available for COM add-ins.

There is no support for events in Word beyond those available in the common API (`activeViewChanged` and `selectionChanged` on the `Document` object).